# Execute certain JavaScript depending on URL

Tags: javascript, php, magento, google-ads-api

A client wants to measure the conversion rate of his Magento webshop through Google Adwords via snippets on the success page of the shop. The Webshop is multilingual with every language having a different URL but they are all based on one Magento installation.

For every language / country they have a different AdWords campaign with their own conversion measurement and therefore their own code snippet.

I know I need to identify users via the URL and then insert the correct snippet accordingly, but how do I do this? Javascript or PHP? Could someone please give me hint.

**My first try**

```
<?php

$currentDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

if ('shop.domain1.com' == $currentDomain) {
    include('domain1script.php');
} elseif ('shop.domain2.com' == $currentDomain) {
    include('domain2script.php');
} elseif ('shop.domain3.com' == $currentDomain) {
    include('domain3script.php');
} elseif ('shop.domain4.com' == $currentDomain) {
    include('domain4script.php');
}
?>
```

**with domain1script.php being:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "scriptstuff"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
    "noscriptstuff"
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with either php, or javascript.

For the sake of simplicity and keeping your JS nice and short I would use PHP. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] should return what you're looking for. :)

This can be achieved in javascript as well, I believe window.location.href contains what you would want to parse?

Comment: Thanks Robby. I already found the PHP method you posted, but I don't know how to implement it correctly. Should I keep all the JavaScript in separate js files and inject them with simple if-statements?

Comment: You can do it with that approach, nothing wrong with that!

How are your urls formatted, I can better help you do the PHP way if you'd prefer that.

Comment: The URLs are just shop.domain1.com, shop.domain2.de, shop.domain3.es, and so on.
I would really appreciate a nod in the right direction.

Comment: Check out $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: Updated my first post. Could you please have a look?